# Is is possible to Generate ~1ppm Copper in Solution from Elemental Copper?

Tags: solubility, concentration

I am designing a hydroponic system and need to control algae.  Copper is a known algaecide and lettuce actually needs some copper to grow well.  I had read stories about people using copper pennies in things like bird baths to reduce algae.  Pennies in the nutrient solution reservoir did not seem to affect the algae much.

I had a thought that by increasing the surface area, I might get a better result.  Fine copper wool is available for finish sanding, and I was thinking about running the nutrient solution through that to try to get some copper into solution.  The nutrient solution is ~pH 6 and 25C and has the (somewhat generic fertilizer) contents shown below at about a 1g/L (~2000uS EC) concentration.  The flow rate is ~4L/min, but only for about a 10 seconds every 300 seconds.  Another option is just to leave the copper in the water reservoir so that it is always in contact with the nutrient solution.

**Is it possible to get ~1ppm of copper into solution from an elemental copper source in the nutrient solution?**

It doesn't matter if it takes a week or so, as long as there is some chance of the copper going into solution.

EDIT:

I found [this paper on Cu/Zn soluability vs pH.](http://www.conference.net.au/chemeca2011/papers/477.pdf)  It contains the graph below.

**Is it true that assuming that ‎Cu2+ ions have 63.546 g/mol weight, and 1ppm = 1mg/L, that 0.001g/L * 1/63.546 mol/g => 15uM solution, and thus the graph indicates that at pH 6.5 there will definitely be more than 1ppm of copper in solution at 25C?**

[image]

[image: Nutrient Label]

Comment: Just buy better fertiliser.

Comment: @Mithoron Is my question edit sufficient for removing the hold?

Comment: This graph is for equilibrium with hydroxide not metal, also it suggests the opposite of what you state. And my earlier comment still holds...